# Installing Ubuntu In Another Drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have to drives in my computer. My main hard drive (with windows installed) and my data hard drive.

My data hard drive has two partitions, one with data (200 GB) and one where I want to install Ubuntu (300 GB).

**Drive Setup**

```
--Main Hard Drive  
--Data Hard Drive With Two Partitions {  
----Partition One (200 GB, Has My Music And Videos)  
--Partition Two (300 GB, I want to install Ubuntu on it
```

How would I install Ubuntu in my 300 GB partition, and if I do, how do I boot to it. My computer's startup drive order, is set up to start up my main hard drive. So if I did install it how would I boot into it without having to change my boot order?

Answer (score 1):

You should have no problems with your installation. Just do what I suggest below, and everything should be good.

1. Create some form of install media (USB or DVD, or even PXE if you know how), and boot into it.
2. When prompted with options on where you want to install Ubuntu, choose `Something Else...`.
3. On the next screen, select the partition you want to install Ubuntu on, right click it and go into its properties.
4. Here, format it as `ext4` and mount(use) it as `/`.
5. Exit out of that property dialog.

   - Now, hopefully you have EFI, which you probably do. The first partition on the main hard drive should be a ~100MB partition formatted as FAT32.
6. Go into its properties and make sure it's mounted(used) as `/boot/EFI`.

   - **Don't format this one.**
7. Exit out and continue with the installation.

When you reboot, GRUB should come up with the options to boot into Ubuntu or Windows.